# How should I proceed on proving that vectors pointing to the vertices of an n-simplex all have negative dot products with one another?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am unsure on how to prove this statement. I am relatively certain that it is true, any advice on how to start?

Edit: It has occurred to me that this will be significantly easier to show by restricting the simplex to be regular (and may be only true in this case).

Comment: What gives you this intuition? I would start by defining arbitrary vectors, doing a dot product and then applying restrictions to the values based on the n-simplex you want to define

Comment: I've seen it stated many times without proof (by well respected folk). I'll give your advice a try, many thanks

Comment: I assume the vectors are pointing from somewhere inside the simplex (that is, the simplex is centered around the origin)? This shouldn't be true if you move the simplex far from the origin.

Comment: I assumed the same thing desiigner, otherwise obviously you could get all the vectors to be positive and thus have positive dot products.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have been more specific. I am assuming that the simplex is around the origin (or more generally the vectors are from the center of the simplex).

Comment: What about an arbitrary triangle in the plane?

Comment: Can you also clarity if you mean some specific standard n-simplex or an arbitrary one?

Comment: Arbitrary regular n-simplex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Note: Some of my $n$s are off by one because the simplexes I was thinking about weren't the standard simplexes. I don't think that changes the core idea though, and this is only a sketch of an idea.]

I haven't worked this all the way out, but it's got an $n$ in it, so why not try induction?

It feels like you should be able to express the vectors for an $n+1$ simplex as {the vectors for an $n$ simplex} plus (the vector from the $n$ center to the $n+1$ center), along with one new vector for the new vertex. Then you have to show 1) you still have a negative dot product for the old vectors, even after adding on the center-to-center vector, and 2) the vector for the new vertex has a negative dot product with all the previous vectors.

Edit - Adding details on the induction: I think of an n-simplex as lying in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and you build an $(n+1)$-simplex by mapping $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as 
$$(x_1, ... x_n) \mapsto (x_1, ... x_n, 0)$$
and then you add a new vertex that becomes the "top of the pyramid" and the embedded $n$-simplex becomes the base of the $n+1$-simplex. BTW, as I'm explaining this I'm realizing you could either track the vertices **or** track the vectors from your center to the vertices when doing your induction. I'm not sure which would be cleaner/easier.

I'll confess that I'm still not sure which class of simplexes you want to prove this for, so I'm not even sure that this construction always applies to all the cases you're interested in, but it works for the standard simplexes we used in algebraic topology, and it might let you figure out how to construct counter-examples if you find that you can't carry the induction forward.

Comment: This is a great approach, I would try something like this. Prove it first for a simple case like a triangle and then if you can just get an inductive step you'll be done.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the addition of vectors in an n-dimensional space to an n+1-dimensional space. Would you mind clarifying that? Induction definitely seems like the way to go in general, as the base case is incredibly simple.

Answer (score 1):

If the "origin" is *arbitrary*, then the statement is clearly wrong: if it is sufficiently far enough from the simplex, the vectors from it to the vertices are almost collinear.

Even for a regular triangle and the origin *inside* it, but close to one of the vertices, the angle between the the vectors pointing to the other two vertices will be acute - almost $\pi/2$.

Even if the origin is the *centroid* of the simplex, it is still false for an arbitrary simplex because one can arrange the vertices almost along a circle and the angles for "neighboring" vertices will be $2\pi/n$.

However, for a *regular simplex* and its *center* all the dot products are the same and it is pretty easy to compute: in $n$-dimensional space, the regular $n-1$-dimensional simplex with $n$ vertices has the standard orthonormal basis $(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$ for vertices and the centroid is $(1/n,...,1/n)$. The dot product in question is:

$$
2\times(-\frac1n)(1-\frac1n)+(n-2)\times(-\frac1n)(-\frac1n)
= - \frac2n+\frac2{n^2} +\frac{n}{n^2}-\frac2{n^2}
=-\frac1n < 0
$$

More **generally**, given a segment, the locus of points from which the segment is seen under an obtuse angle is the interior of the sphere having the segment as its diameter. Thus the locus of point such that the vectors from it to the vertices of a simplex have all negative dot products is precisely the intersection of spheres that have simplex edges as diameters, IOW, those points whose distances to the edge centers are less than the half edge length.

Comment: Even though I gave an answer on how to prove it I suspect you may be right. The only question(s)I have is with your regular simplex remarks. The one you described, with $0$ and $1$ values for co-ordinates, is what I think of as the "standard simplex", but I don't think it's regular. A regular one has all edges the same length. I also don't think $(1 ...1)$ is the center. It would help if the original poster made their question more precise.

Comment: My simplex is the standard regular simplex. I fixed the typo you pointed out.

Comment: Oops, turns out my concept of what the "standard simplex" is is different from the rest of the world. Apologies.